# mongodb, select the records with a field that appears at least N times in the collection

Tags: mongodb, optimization, mapreduce

i'm have a collection with data in this format(much bigger actually, but this is the part we are interested in):

```
{
    'id': 123214546565,
    'user': {
        id: 2222222
        }
}
```

with id as a key and user.id can be duplicate across the collections.

i'm tring to extrac all the user.id that appear in the db more than 20 times.

i'm new to mongo and i'm no good with javascript and i'v tried various things, without results, i suppose i should use a MapReduce, but i'm failing hard with the javascript part.

i can't simply search for it on the client as the mongod instance is over the network and so i should minimize the data i send.

with something like this:

```
db.data.find({}, {'user.id':1, _id: 0})
```

i find all the user.id, but i'd still like to filter out the ones with less than 20 repetitions before, to send even less data(we are talking about ten thousands of records so it's a lot of data over the internet)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on MongoDB v2.2+ I recommend using the new aggregation framework.

Here is the command to extract `user.id` appearing more than 20 times on the collection.

```
db.data.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$user.id', hits: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {hits: {$gt: 20}}}])
```

[MongoDB Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)